# Angular 2 routes load different component based on type of parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need to load different components based on the type of route parameter. if the route parameters is string then load one component like below,

`{ path: 'care/action/:string',component: StringComponent},`

if the route parameters is number then load another component like below

`{ path: 'care/action/:number', component: NumberComponent},`

Please note that URL will remain same, only type of parameter will change.

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a router resolve and then load a different template depending upon the resolve .

there is no need of different components different templates can do the thing

Comment: @RahulSingh, how to load templates depending on resolve?

Comment: using the new if else blocjk of angular or when you get values from resolve you have two structural directives i:e ngIf and check which value is true and then show that particular div or block or if you use templates show that

Comment: We are using Angular2 and ``new if else block of angular`` is not available in this version i think.

Comment: then use normal if else and use a variable that you subscribe to the resolve and check the value and depending upon that you display the proper block or div

Comment: But is it possible to load different template without using resolve.

Comment: this is one of the method i think will be easy and also modular it depends you can also use regex as deezg pointed out but  i have not used that so i wnt comment

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggestions.  Hope to find solution soon :-)

Comment: i was thinking about the solution we can also use this. Take the path param from the url check the path param in the component to see if it is a strig or number using regex and then display block. This is easy and simple i feel. And you can do this inside nginit block in component

Comment: Yea we could do that, But i think i should have informed you this before (since our requirement is bit long which i can not explain in detail here) in my case there is a resolve for URL if the parameter is number else there will be no resolve.  Resolve will make HTTP get request to REST API based on parameter number . In case URL with string, we need to load another component (kind of all details in one page) which will make several  HTTP request.

Comment: then the best way is to use is router resolve and the previous way i suggested i feel ur call

Comment: Yea you are right. Will dig bit deeper and revert back to with my solution. Anyways thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

You might want to leverage matcher property on your route configs and pass a matching function to it. Your matcher function would use regular expression to check if its a string (for string route) or number (for number).

Comment: Thanks. Can you please point me to some resources where i can find examples on this?

Comment: unfortunately, its not documented yet but you can see example in the source code: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d58a242fe7b1d0e664733df3adfcbc458ec9dc67/packages/router/src/config.ts#L260-L293

Comment: I found one example @ https://gist.github.com/matanshukry/22fae5dba9c307baf0f364a9c9f7c115. But i am getting error  `ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'routes'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 9:7 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol CareRoutingModule in C:/webserver/GIT/gco2ng/src/app/care
/care-routing.module.ts`. Any idea what might causing this error ??